# How to transfer data from MSSQL to BigQuery using apache Beam (Datafow)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to transfer data from MSSQL to GCP BigQuery or GCP Cloud Storage using apache beam, dataflow. But I found that there is no Built-in connector to do that. Does anyone know how to approach this task using apache beam or dataflow??